# Display Icon in Popup Menu

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, menuitem

I am using latest app compact library for my android application. I want display Icon with my menu but its does not showing.

its looking like this

[image]

My Java Codes Like this

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }
```

and XML is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_bg"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_text"
        android:title="@string/bg"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_font"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_text"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/font"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_create"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_text"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/create_photo"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_copy"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_text"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/copy"/>

</menu>
```

Let me know if someone can help me to get icons with menu text.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to add icons in support library, but that trick can help

```
<menu>
  <item> // fake item
    <menu> // submenu
      <item /> // your item with icon
      <item /> // your item with icon
      <item /> // your item with icon
    </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```